# Feed intermediate value and evaluate subgraph in a tf.Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorflow-estimator

I am training a variational autoencoder with `tf.Estimator`. The `model_fn` contains an encoder and a decoder and takes images as input. In deployment or evaluation phase, I would like the model to take a randomly sampled latent code as input and only execute the decoder part.

Is a way I can disentangle encoder and decoder from my estimator?

Answer (score 0):

If you use a [variable_scope](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/variable_scope) for your decoder you can generate a random sample in your `model_fn` and then pass that through the decoder again by creating a `variable_scope` using the same name with `reuse=True`.

Pseudocode:

```py
def encoder_fn(image, ...):
  ...
  return latent

def decoder_fn(latent, ...):
  ...
  return reconstruction

def model_fn(...):
  ...

  with tf.variable_scope('encoder'):
    predictions['latent'] = encoder_fn(features[...], ...)

  with tf.variable_scope('decoder'):
    predictions['reconstruction'] = decoder_fn(predictions['latent'], ...)

  with tf.variable_scope('sample'):
    random_latent = ...

  with tf.variable_scope('decoder', reuse=True):
    random_reconstruction = decoder_fn(random_latent, ...)

  ...
```

---

For advanced users another protip is if you add the latent code into the features dictionary it will show up under inputs in your exported savedmodel. Since you can just load the savedmodel into a session this means you can easily access and feed the latent codes directly. It's possible to feed more than just placeholders. A feature that really isn't advertised enough.

Example,

```py
# Train side:
# 1. Create estimator
# 2. Train
# 3. Export savedmodel
def model_fn(...):
  ...

  with tf.variable_scope('encoder'):
    predictions['latent'] = encoder_fn(features[...], ...)
    features['latent'] = predictions['latent']

  with tf.variable_scope('decoder'):
    predictions['reconstruction'] = decoder_fn(predictions['latent'], ...)

  ...

# Client side,
# 1. Launch session
# 2. Load savedmodel

# We can reconstruct images
reconstructed_images = session.run(outputs['reconstruction'], feed_dict={inputs['images'] : my_images))

# And generate directly from latent code
random_images = session.run(outputs['reconstruction'], feed_dict={inputs['latents'] : np.random.normal(...)})

# All in the same graph!
```